# How can I hide my specific Java source code (a single class) by making it non-readable?

Tags: java

How can I hide my specific Java source code (a single class out of several classes) of a software application. I mean, is there a way to make that class can not viewable  or accessible by others? Can we create that class into a library or reference file? And then it can't be viewed by hackers?

Comment: what you want is impossible. at best you can make it more DIFFICULT for the code to be read, but you cannot entirely prevent it. it it couldn't be read at all, then it couldn't be executed either, at which point it becomes entirely useless.

Comment: Once someone has your code, even if its compiled and obfuscated, its possible to reverse engineer it.

Comment: The security of your software should never rely on _obscurity_ alone; "Always assume that an attacker knows everything that you know -- assume the attacker has access to all source code and all designs" (from [Writing Secure Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Writing-Secure-Code-Best-Practices/dp/0735617228)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a way to partially do what you want.

You can use proguard to obfuscate it.

As for completely hiding the class I do not know any way to do that.

Comment: I agree.
The only other way I can imagine is to encrypt the code with some kind of native code and to decrypt it during runtime into the memory. One can use some kind of special Classloader to use these classes directly from memory then

Comment: Thanx Roberto .@Martin , I have no idea about how to decrypt during runtime,If i encrypt the code in source code and decryption algorithm also need to include in the source code no? at least the key must need to include in the source code no? so anyone can decrypt  it no?